# Wordpress user login redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, function, redirect

I'm trying to redirect users to a certain page when logging in using the wordpress login on a certain page (there's a user/pass input on the homepage, not asking about redirect from site.com/wp-login). The code is below; `wpmem_` is from a plugin. This code worked fine when I had a different URL but it's not working since I changed it to `shop`.

```
add_filter( 'wpmem_login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 2 );

function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $user_id ) 
{
    // return the url that the login should redirect to
    return 'http://example.com/shop/';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the function that gets called to redirect the user from the login, try to use the code below instead of the return function.

```
header("Location: http://example.com/shop/");
exit();
```

Comment: Hmm still redirects to the old page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
add_filter( 'wpmem_login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );

function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) 
{
    // return the url that the login should redirect to
    return home_url('shop');
}
```

Comment: Hmm I tried this. Emptied the cache and tried hard refreshing but still nothing.

Comment: Can't you wordpress filter/action ?

Comment: I meant default wordpress action like `template_redirect` or `template_include` ?

Comment: Like the first example on this page? http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect

Answer (score 0):

Insted of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` put your url where you want to redirect

```
if ( (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] != 'logout') || (isset($_POST['login_location']) && !empty($_POST['login_location'])) ) {
    add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
    function my_login_redirect() {
        $location = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        wp_safe_redirect($location);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to the URL provided no matching the site URL, the following worked for me!

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $user_id ) 
{
    return site_url('/shop/');
}
add_filter( 'wpmem_login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```